# How to make selected text stay selected in textarea?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a WYSIWYG editor. I have a textarea and I can get the selected text. But when I click something outside of the textarea the text becomes unselected. I want to make it stay selected unless I select another portion of text or click somewhere in textarea. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

at your HTML

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="mytextfield">
</form>
```

and use method focus

```
<body OnLoad="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();">
```

Answer (score 0):

**(on)select** 
save the start and end position of the selection to the input element itself.

*event.target.lastSelection = { start:startpos, end:endpos};*

and use the [**(on)blur**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur) event to do something like

*event.target.[setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange)( event.target.lastSelection.start, event.target.lastSelection.end )*